# Kubuntu 23.10 Viber.AppImage not opening URLs

Tags: kubuntu, google-chrome, viber

I am using Viber (AppImage, not the .deb) but whenever anyone sends me a URL in chat if i try to open it by clicking it just doesnt open (i have to copy the URL manually and paste it in the browser)

I have tried to set chrome, chromium and firefox as default browser and none opens the link (it does via the .deb version installed but that one has more severe issues so i prefer not to use it).

Anyone familiar with this issue? I can provide more information of course but I dont know where to look, I have checked syslog but dont see anything too suspicious.

Thank you.

EDIT:
I was able to extract the following logs:

> /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable: /tmp/.mount_viber.JQuWlK/usr/lib/libnss3.so: version `NSS_3.65' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmime3.so)
>
> [7717:10312:0127/181921.447209:ERROR:nss_util.cc(232)] Error initializing NSS with a persistent database (sql:/home/***/.pki/nssdb): NSS error code: -8023

Comment: Same problem with Ubuntu 23.10 and viber.AppImage but the logs are slightly different:
`sed: /tmp/.mount_viber.Qjp0Gb/usr/lib/libselinux.so.1: no version information available (required by sed)
    cannot open path of the current working directory: Permission denied`

Comment: I just installed Viber as a flatpak package - it works like a charm on Wayland session. I have no more patience to deal with the `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` error on the `deb` version and the URL issue you described with the `AppImage` version.